# how can show silder look when navigate one html page another in phonegap?

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

Right now I am developing PhoneGap app all functionality are successfully done which what client need but in my PhoneGap app I am using multiple html pages on click of one button index.html it will naviagte to another html but client need silder look when naviagte one page to another page..

Code is:

```
<li><a onclick="callFestvialinfo()"><img src="images/festival_info_button.png" width="123" height="123" alt="" /></a></li>
```

---

```
function callFestvialinfo()
{                 
window.location = "festival_info.html";
}
```

it will navigate `festival_info.html` normally but client need silder look from index to `festival_info.html` and `festival_info.html` to index when onclick back.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out. A very light weight solution to page transitions.

http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/